# Scaling an image in Java Swt & memory consumption

Tags: java, image, swt, scaling

i have a java swt application. In the resize method of a container i'd like to resize the image, which is shown using the following code. However seems like - even i dispose everything (really?) the memory consumption is increasing all the time...
I can't find my mistake. Why and where this code eats up all my memory?

Here is the Resize-Listener:

```
tabCover.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            // Set images: cover_front
            int width = tabCover.getSize().x - 30;
            int height = tabCover.getSize().y - 30;
            Image buffer_Coverfront;

            buffer_Coverfront = new Image(Display.getDefault(), filename);
            lblCoverfront.setImage(Helper.ImageScale(buffer_Coverfront, width, height));
            buffer_Coverfront.dispose();
            buffer_Coverfront = null;

        } // handleEvent
    }); // Listener
```

And here the scaling function:

```
public static Image ImageScale(Image image, int width, int height) {


    ImageData data = image.getImageData();

    // Some logic to keep the aspect ratio
    float img_height = data.height;
    float img_width = data.width;
    float container_height = height;
    float container_width = width;

    float dest_height_f = container_height;
    float factor = img_height / dest_height_f;

    int dest_width = (int) Math.floor(img_width / factor );
    int dest_height = (int) dest_height_f;

    if(dest_width > container_width) {
        dest_width = (int) container_width;
        factor = img_width / dest_width;
        dest_height = (int) Math.floor(img_height / factor);

    }

    // Image resize
    data = data.scaledTo(dest_width, dest_height);
    Image scaled = new Image(Display.getDefault(), data);
    image.dispose();
    return scaled;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from the `handleEvent(...)` method, you forget to dispose the old image.

```
tabCover.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // Set images: cover_front
        int width = tabCover.getSize().x - 30;
        int height = tabCover.getSize().y - 30;
        Image buffer_Coverfront;

        buffer_Coverfront = new Image(Display.getDefault(), filename);
        Image old = lblCoverfront.getImage();
        lblCoverfront.setImage(Helper.ImageScale(buffer_Coverfront, width, height));
        buffer_Coverfront.dispose();
        buffer_Coverfront = null;

        if (old != null) old.dispose();

    } // handleEvent
}); // Listener
```

The code above assumes that the image of the control is *only* set in this method. If you also set the initial image from, somewhere else, then the condition of the disposal have to be refined...

Comment: Thanks, this hint helped. I changed the relevant part to:        ` Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), filename_front);
            Image scaled = Helper.ImageScale(image, width, height);
            lblCoverfront.setImage(scaled);
            image.dispose();
            scaled.dispose();`

Answer (score 2):

As i can't post the code in the comment, here it is:

```
tabCover.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            // Set images: cover_front
            int width = tabCover.getSize().x - 30;
            int height = tabCover.getSize().y - 30;

                String filename_front = my_collection.getGlobal_path() + "Cover/" + selected_movie.getCover_front();

                try {
                    Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), filename_front);
                    Image scaled = Helper.ImageScale(image, width, height);
                    lblCoverfront.setImage(scaled);
                    image.dispose();
                    scaled.dispose();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                } // end try

        } // handleEvent
    }); // Listener
```

Thanks again to Tonny Madsen for the useful tip.

Comment: With SWT,we have to remember to properly dispose fonts, images and colors... A very, very common error. Next tie, have a look at sleak...